# Unable to retrieve postgres password

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, psql, pgadmin

I know there are so many questions around this stuff, but the problem I encountered is
I had installed long ago Postgres but when i tried to  [reset my password according to this](http://astonj.com/tech/how-to-recover-or-reset-a-lost-postgresql-password/), third instruction suggests to open the "pg_hba.conf"
file. But to open a file also needs password. So after all googling decided to delete the existing setup then also it is asking password.

Please help me out

Comment: On which platform? windows, linux...

Comment: @Tommaso Di Bucchianico linux platform

Comment: Access to the `pg_hba.conf` is controlled by your operating system. Typically this file (and all other Postgres configuration files) are owned by the **Linux** user `postgres`. So you either need to `su postgres` or use the `root` account to change that file.

Comment: To edit your pg_hba.conf file you need to open the file as system administrator. See http://ccm.net/faq/8329-how-to-execute-command-as-administrator-under-linux. What do you mean with 'delete the existing setup'? Did you reinstall PostgreSql?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes i have sudo rights.

Comment: @ Tommaso Di Bucchianico, i meant uninstalling it and then reinstalling

Answer (score 0):

Probably your server has already the ident login option for the user postgres. 
If so, you can login by first doing `sudo su postgres`, than `psql` in a terminal:

```
sudo su postgres
psql
```

If this does work, but you want to login with a password and without sudo, you need to set a password, modify your pg_hba.conf and than reload the Postgres server

1) Set a password for the user postgres:
log in in psql as described above an than do in psql:

```
ALTER USER postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'your_password';
```

2) Modify your pg_hba.conf. [Open the file as administrator](http://ccm.net/faq/8329-how-to-execute-command-as-administrator-under-linux) and change this line

```
local all postgres ident
```

to this

```
local all postgres md5
```

3) Now reload the postgres server:

```
sudo service postgresql reload
```

Now can you login with the user postgres:

```
psql -U postgres
```